# ASP.NET 2.0 website white screen of death

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am encountering a strange issue which is only affecting several users from an over 7000 user-base. Having searched the web for several hours to no avail, I'm hoping someone here can help!

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 website and when certain users try to access the home page (Default.aspx) they receive a white screen with no content loaded. This issue is occurring both in production environment and if I run the solution against a copy of production data. So I am able to replicate the exact same issue when I pseudo the problematic users.

When debugging the application in VS2005 and set a breakpoint in the code behind in the Default.aspx, the breakpoints are fired/hit so I know the request is working. The problem seems to be once the server has finished serving the request, the response back to the client/browser is empty.

Here's another strange thing I've noticed. If I alter the HTML in Default.aspx by adding a new white line or whitespace, the page will load fine for the same set of users. I thought I had resolved the issue with this fix but unfortunately the white screen issue just manifests itself once again.

Within Default.aspx, there's some AJAX requests using jQuery .load function but this can't be the issue because this functionality exists for every user of the site. The only variable is the amount of content returned within this request can vary depending on the user. But why would it resolve itself when I put a whitespace or whiteline in the page and then manifest itself hours later?

Another thing to note is it's only Default.aspx that is encountering this issue. If I browse to another page by typing in a page in the address bar, the page is served OK.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction on how I can debug or even resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you getting a response in the Net tab in Firebug?

Comment: Is it the entire default page that doesn't get rendered? Or just the AJAX result?

Comment: Are the browsers the same? is this **internet** or **intranet**?

Comment: What exactly is "white screen of death"? Can you get a user to do a "View Source" and send it to you? Can you get a network trace of some kind? Otherwise, you're just guessing (and so are we).

Comment: Do you have any httphandlers intercepting the request? Also, times when I've seen the response get probed was due to a compression issue.

Comment: @mxmissile - Net tab in Firebug displays return 0B and the response is 200 OK.

Comment: @JoeEnos - It is the entire default page that doesn't get rendered.

Comment: @christiandev - It's an intranet app. I've tested with IE6, IE7, IE8 and Firefox and all experiencing same issue.

Comment: @PhilCooper - I think you're pointing me in the right direction here. We're using a third party HttpModule called DC.Web.HttpCompress.HttpModule. If I exclude the Default.aspx (culprit) from the compression, the page works and loads as expected. But why does this work for some users and not others? The page is almost identical for every user except for the AJAX content that is loaded.

Comment: @creativeincode sorry, no idea regarding that. The time I had something like this, the app was trying compress during an action execution (mvc) and I needed to put a check to prevent compressing the response.  Can you debug the module?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your ajax *is* the cause but without seeing some code, it's difficult to know why.

It could be a timeout, or an error that is preventing the ajax from completing it's function.

You need to use a tool like Charles or Fiddler to debug what is happening whilst the page loads whilst logged in as these users. In a nutshell, a tool like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) will display all the detail surrounding requests made and responses served to the browser, including any failed responses.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I was using Fiddler to check the request and responses but the response returned is 0B but the response is 200 - OK.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was using Fiddler to check the request and responses but the response returned is 0B with 200 - OK. If AJAX is causing the issue, I would expect the page to still load fine and for the AJAX part to fail as it's a separate request that is fired as part of jQuery's document.ready event once the DOM has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with http headers, caching or encoding. But I cannot tell more without code.

Is output caching enabled for this page?

Can you give us the raw http headers for both the request and response?

If a white screen appears, will it be fixed by pressing ctrl+f5?